# NestJS TypeORM oneToMany has error - invalid column name

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nest

I'm working on NestJS + SQLSERVER.
I got error when I try to get a relation data. What I got is,

> QueryFailedError: Error: Invalid column name 'roleId'.

Here is my user.entity,

```
@Entity({ name: 'dbo.tbl_users' })
export class User {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({name:'user_id'}) 
  id: number;

  @Column({
    name: 'EmployeeNo',
    length: 255
  }) employeeNo: string;

  @Column({
    name: 'FirstNameEN',
    length: 255
  }) firstNameEN: string;

  @Column({
    name: 'LastNameEN',
    length: 255
  }) lastNameEN: string;

  @Column({
    name: 'Email',
    length: 255
  }) email: string;

  @Column({
    name: 'MobileNo',
    length: 255
  }) mobileNo: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Role, role => role.users)
  role: Role;
}
```

And here is my role.entity,

```
@Entity({ name: 'dbo.tbl_roles' })
export class Role {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({name:'role_id'}) 
  id: number;

  @Column({
    name: 'role_name',
    length: 255
  }) 
  roleName: string;

  @Column({
    name: 'created_at',
  }) 
  createdAt: Date;

  @OneToMany(() => User, user => user.role)
  users: User[];
  
}
```

I do not know why the error asks for **roleId** because I do not have this variable in the project. There is also no **roleId** column in my database. And the error do not tell where the **roleId** is needed.

Please help. Thanks.